Allocating complex data (btVector3) on the stack in LLVM IR
I want to use LLVM to JIT compile some code in my game using the LLVM C/C++ API. The JIT compiled functions should be able to effect the physics of the world, which is handled by bullet3.
To do so I need/want to allocate some space on the stack for a btVector3. This class is not simply a four element array of floats, but fulfills many alignment and SIMD properties, so I think manually creating a struct type would be hard and difficult to maintain.
Is there a way to load the definitions from the btVector3.h file into a LLVM module?
I already tried a few things:

I tried to compile the btVector3.h file into a shared object file using g++. This does not work as neither nm nor readelf recognize the resulting file as a valid object.
I tried compiling the btVector3.h file into a .bc file using clang++ -c -emit-llvm. This also faces the same issue when using llvm-nm to check the resulting file.
I also tried to create a proxy file that uses all necessary functions and then compile the proxy. This works for accessing functions like btVector3::x() in the resulting shared object file, but does not allow me to access the definition of the structure itself.

I can work around the issue by simplifying the btVector3 object to a 16bit align float array, and then every time I want to pass a vector to an extern function void foo(btVector3&) I could call a function like:
void _foo(float* p)
{
    btVector3 v(p[0], p[1], p[2]);

    foo(v);

    p[0] = v.x();
    p[1] = v.y();
    p[2] = v.z();
}

which I compile into a shared object file beforehand. This feels bad, but would fix the problem and I could even imagine that the JIT optimizer would inline this function, which could fix the problem.
I would be happy about either a way to directly incorporate the definitions as I have stated in the beginning. I would also be happy about any other work around ideas.

As I understand your problem, there are two basic approaches: ① Automatically generate an array type an alloca that, and ② automatically generate a complicated struct type and alloca that.

Exactly, but how can I generate them automatically. Idealy I could call something like StructType *btVector3Ty = StructType::create(context, btVector3). But to my knowlage there is no such constructor.

I looked at some similar code and saw a three-call sequence: getIfExists() and if that's null, create(), and if that has no body fields, setBody().

Sorry for the late answer. I do not understand how you're suggestion fixes my problem. On what should I call getIfExists()? If I try to look for "btVector3" it will always return null because I did not manually register it yet, no?

That wasn't clear in the code at which I looked. In that code, different call paths might create the StructType, including one that loaded a previously written Module from a file and implicitly created all of the types used in that file. If you know that you'll never load a Module from file, you shouldn't need getIfExists().
